# Scrapy how can I make spiders wait for each other? (maximum concurrent users)

Tags: scrapy

We use scrapy to login and crawl several websites at the same time, this works great. Only some websites need to be crawled twice with different settings. Two spiders were created (and this cant be changed). THe problem is that when we login to website X for brand A tha all works fine, a msec later we login to website X for brand B ..... but this is where the error occurs. The website only allows 1 concurrent user at a time.

So either it should use the other spiders session instead of logging in itself? Only how can this be done.

But rather my question is: how can we make spider B detect the active crawling of A and pause() the crawler before it logs in. I found some code below where 2 spiders are based on 1 parent class. This is also our setup.

How can we make spider B wait for spider A to finish and then continue?

[image]

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: Can paste code later. As it is dad/wrong example ans as looking for correct way we posted image